# How to host a minecraft server without portforwarding

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have a VPS that I dont use but it dosn't Have much ram. I setup a minecraft server on my PC but I don't want to port forward. Is there any way I can use a SSH Tunnel to let my server work?

Comment: Why don't you want to port forward that is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I'm Not Currently allowed. Unless I can get my server on a different subnet.

Comment: You sure you even need port forwarding most applications suppor UPuP

Comment: I'm Sure that port forwarding is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it through ssh try using -L option

```
 -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This works by allocating a
         socket to listen to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection
         is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port hostport from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be specified in
         the configuration file.  IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing the address in square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged ports.
         By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the connection
         to a specific address.  The bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’
         indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.
```

You will need to connect via ssh to server (with this option) and then leave that ssh connection running, so you can use port forwarding. Your server should be then available at 127.0.0.1:port

Answer (score 0):

I hosted a server at my university with a good deal of success using Logmein's hamachi program.  Your clients would need to install the software, but you can create a customized executable that they can setup without manually entering in any settings.

An IPv6 Tunnel may be another option if minecraft supports this.